# Youtube onPlayerReady does not always run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I'm trying to implement Youtube's video player on [this][1] page.

I wanted the video player to play in a lightbox when a link was clicked on the page, or to pop up when you linked to the video ([example link][2]).  I'm "mostly" happy with how it's working.  The things that I am having issues with are these two separate things.

1) On some computers (not browser specific), sometimes (not always) the onPlayerReady (event) function will not run.  The code for the pop-up is inside this function, so the video doesn't play.  The only common factor I can find is that 100% of the time it works when you refresh the page.

2) When you click a link before the page is finished loading, the video player loads, however the video itself is not loaded.  I assume the loadVideoById function isn't running. I'm not sure how to stop people from making this mistake.  Again, it works perfectly if you close the player and reopen it.

When you visit from a link the page refreshes to a url that doesn't include the anchor in order to keep people from getting stranded on the linked page.  This is not an error.

I'm not sure what you need to see since there is a live demo, so I'm not going to clutter this up by including a bunch of stuff you don't need.  I will instead respond or edit with whatever code you need to see.

If you find any other glaring errors please let me know.

EDIT: The community was apparently helpless to even respond to my question.  I worked around the problem using a different process so the question is no longer applicable.  I'm disappointed in this community that came together to critique and edit my question, but had not a single suggestion for me.

EDIT2: Links Removed